# OpenCV - Tensorflow model import error

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I use ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model with OpenCV for object detection.

```
cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')
```

When using original graph.pbtxt it is OK.
But when i create pbtxt file using tf_text_graph_ssd
    https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py

```
python tf_text_graph_ssd.py --input frozen_inference_graph.pb --output pbtxt/frozen_inference_graph.pbtxt
```

and then:

```
cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'pbtxt/frozen_inference_graph.pbtxt')
```

it gives error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Input layer not found: 
FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/zeros) in 
cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::`anonymous-
namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet, file C:
\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp, 
line 1061
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opencv_tensorflow.py", line 3, in <module>
cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 
'pbtxt/frozen_inference_graph.pbtxt')
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-
python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:1061: error: (-2) 
Input layer not found: FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/zeros in function cv::d
nn::experimental_dnn_v3::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet
```

What is the problem when converting pb to pbtxt?

Here my aim is create custom model using image retraining and use it on OpenCV.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

So I have a custom model but not pbtxt file.

First i try to create pbtxt for an example ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same :(

Answer (score 1):

I can create pbtxt file using tf_text_graph_ssd.py with below command.

```
    python tf_text_graph_ssd.py --input=C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\anas\Robomy\tfLearn\cell_inference_graph\frozen_inference_graph.pb --output=C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\anas\Robomy\tfLearn\cell_inference_graph\ssd_mobilenet_v1_balls_2018_05_20.pbtxt --config C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\anas\Robomy\tfLearn\data\ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config
```

this pbtxt worked perfectly on opencv

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify config file as well. I consider if you have done transfer learning using tensorflow API, then you will find a file named pipeline.config along with frozen_inference_graph.pb file. Use that file as --config pipeline.config along with syntax. It should solve the problem.